# Python scribbler, making my robot go in a circle X secs

Tags: python

I am trying to make my robot go in a circle for x seconds. This is what I have:

```
def circle():
for t in timer(4.54):
    motors(1,0)    
circle() 

def main():
circle()

main()
```

But it does not stop at 4.54 seconds, it just keeps on going. Please help, Thank you

Comment: It's impossible to tell because the indentation of your code is messed-up, but it looks like function `circle()` may be calling itself...which means it would never return and so would go on indefinitely (until the stack overflows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to interpret @martineau's comment, try:

```
def circle():
    for t in timer(4.54):
        motors(1,0)
def main():
    circle()
main()
```

If that doesn't work, check the following two points (guesses at the problem without knowledge of your robot's OS:

- How long the function `motors()` runs for
- Whether `timer(4.54)` runs for 4.54 seconds or 4.54 minutes, hours, or some other unit of time

Comment: What was the problem @dave?